# VBA macro needs to be changed from activeworkbook to a specific workbook/sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a automatic e-mail from VBA that takes a specific range. but now the macro is taking the specific range of an active sheet. I dont know how to specify my workbook and sheet properly.. maybe someone can help?

```
Sub Send()


Dim r As Range

Set r = Range("rm")

With r

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

With .Parent.MailEnvelope.Item
.To = ""
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Automatic Message: E-comm numbers Today"
.Send

End With

End With




End Sub
```

it should be in this workbook/sheet

```
Workbooks("Copy of Copy of shipments 5.1.xlsm").Sheets("rapportages")
```

hope you can help :)!

Comment: Is the workbook you need the range in always open when you run the macro?

Comment: @DirtyDeffy, yes it is! but if i'm in another workbook then it sends the range of the workbook i'm in...

Comment: Have a look at this link:  [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).  It covers the active sheet, active book, etc.

Comment: replace `ActiveWorkbook` for `Workbooks("Copy of Copy of shipments 5.1.xlsm")`

Comment: Hi @Aneta thanks for the tip but it still send the current worksheet that I'm in at that moment..

Comment: Maybe you will have to activate the workbook first to work with your range; maybe try to add a line like: Workbooks("Copy of Copy of shipments 5.1.xlsm").Activate before you set r and start your with.

Answer (score 1):

Use [fully qualified references](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/referring_to_ranges_in_your_vba_code/):

```
Set r = Workbooks("Copy of Copy of shipments 5.1.xlsm"). _
    Sheets("rapportages").Range("rm")
```

When you don't do that Excel constructs the `range` object from the active workbook instead of the one you want in this case.

Comment: Hi Miqi even whit this changed it still send my current worksheet i'm working in.. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @vanleeuw Something else is going on than in the code snippets you posted then. Please make an edit and post more relevant code below, if you want us to look into it.